A circle and a point being homotopic to each other
Background
I am trying to understand why a disk and a point are in the same homotopy.
In broad terms, I understand that two functions $f_0, f_1$ are homotopic iff there is a continuous blend from one to the other. The more formal definition is that there is a continuous map
$$H: X \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$$
Such that $X, Y$ are the domain and co-domain of $f_i$, and $H(0, x) = f_0(x)$, $H(1, x) = f_1(x)$.
Then two topological spaces $X, Y$ are homotopically equivalent iff $g \circ f$ is homotopic to the identity on $X$ and $f \circ g$ is homotopic to the identity on $Y$ with $f: X \rightarrow Y; g: Y \rightarrow X$.
Question
The textbook I have says that a disk and a point are homotopically equivalent. So that would mean that there are two functions, whose compositions can be continuously blended to the identity, one on the circle the other on the point.
This is where I start getting confused. Since the point only has a single element, the only kinds of functions you can make from $P$ to $D$ (point space and disk space) are single pairs $g(p) = (p, x_c)$ between the point and some element of the disk.
So I don't see how it is possible to blend a composition involving any of these functions with the identity on the disk?

Circle is not the same as a disk.

@MoisheKohan typo, sorry

The composition does not have to be the identity on the disk, it just has to be homotopic to the identity.
Suppose $f$ maps a point to the center of the disk and $g$ maps the whole disk to the point. Then $f \circ g$ is the identity map on the point while $g \circ f$ maps the whole disk to its center. Now show that $g \circ f$ is homotopic to  the identity map on the disk by finding a continuous deformation $H$.
